How to compute the confidence interval of root mean square (e.g., ci of the RMS of the alternating current signal)
If $\bf x$ are $N$ measurement of alternating current signal (sinusoidal), its root mean square is computed using $RMS=\sqrt{\frac{\sum{x_i^2}}{N}}$.
My question is: Does the confidence interval exist for the $RMS$? How to compute the c.i. of the $RMS$?

Welcome to Cross Validated! I thought RMS in this context was equal to the variance of a distribution with a mean assumed to be zero. Is that correct?

@Dave The RMS will be square root of the variance. And yes, the mean value is assumed to be zero.

For a "confidence interval" to be meaningful, there has to be some randomness somewhere, and there doesn't appear to be here.  Or am I misunderstanding / overlooking something?

@jbowman my thought was that the signal might be a bit noisy, or the signal is shifting over time, e.g. The current of a motor driving a varying load. In such scenario, the RMS at different time slices will behave like random variable and will be statistically distributed.

Then what you'll want is the deviation of the $x_i$ from the true sinusoid, or, failing that, some estimate of the sinusoid, because the RMS shouldn't contain variability that you can predict.

@jbowman Thanks for the insights. I might have given incorrect information. The RMS exists not only for sinusoid signal. My current practice is to divide the samples into many segments in time, you could find the RMS of each segment. These samples' mean and stddev are used for building the c.i. (mean +- 3*stddev). However, I am not sure whether this approach makes sense statistically or not.
